# display tooltips to dynamically generated chart

Tags: c#, graphics, webforms, charts, gdi

Is there a way to display tooltips on an image that is dynamically created. The image is a dynamically created chart that has multiple points and on mouse over on a specific point I need to show additional information via a popup.

I'm using a web forms .net 4.0 and using the System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Imaging namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only output is a flat image, you could try adding a `<map>` to your page and set the 'title' attribute of each `<area>` to your tooltip value.

You can learn more about creating maps here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Essentially, you're defining regions of your image as hot spots.

Comment: do you have any sample code - I'm not sure I understand - thanks

Comment: Read the tutorials, if you still have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: snippet of code:`<area shape="circle" coords="<%=X1Coord%>,<%=Y1Coord%>,8" href="#" alt="" onmouseover="tooltip.show('<%=Desciption%>');" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly where the point is, you could create an image map. But will be cumbersome.
How to make an image map:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

I would recommend that you use a Javascript Charting Library, there are tons of them out there. And there are some good free ones.

We are using Highchart
http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock

But this is not free.

Comment: I do know where the point is - could you point me the way to create an image map.

Comment: the Javascript charting library would not work since the chart is being generated in the code behind and this unit of work is complete.

Comment: Actually, you can still use your data from the code behind. Just create an array with the datapoints and send it to the client. It will be much sexier like that :-)

Comment: I'm leaning towards that - essentially create the image on the fly and then display tooltips on mouse over using (saY) jquery. I can get the point coordinates...

Comment: Remy,going on what you last said about getting the datapoints from the client side, can you recommend any jquery pluggins I could use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a image map, but in order to do that, you're going to need the exact coordinates and if you're off by just a little bit, it could be messed up. Have you given any thought to using MS Charting? http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422

With MS Charting, everything is done on the code behind and it generates an image just as the way you're doing it now. The difference is on the backend, when you create the datapoint, you can set the tool tip and several other properties like this:

```
DataPoint.ToolTip = "Your Tooltip Here";
```

If you are unfamiliar with them, there is a ton of documentation and samples online.

Good Luck!

Comment: MSCharting is *not* an option and that holds true for any other 3rd party tool, hence the question!

Comment: client requirement - besides that requisite server side code is tested and generating the chart real time and all that needs to be done is tooltips for the generated data points hence the question.